# One liner to replicate lines coming from a file (Python)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a regular list comprehension to load all lines of a file in a list

```
f = open('file')

try:
    self._raw = [L.rstrip('\n') for L in f]
finally:
    f.close()
```

Now I'd like to insert in the list each line 'n' times on the fly. How to do it inside the list comprehension ?

Tnx

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you with my basic question, but I'd like to ask - what does self._raw mean?

Answer (score 6):

```
self._raw = [L.rstrip('\n') for L in f for _ in xrange(n)]
```